# Mysql not being updated

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to update a database using php.

The site im working on , i have a local copy and a copy on a server.

It works locally , but on the server it shows that it worked , but does not update the database.

I have checked that the id and data variables do actually have a value and teh connection is working.

This is my code :

```
<?php
include("../../config/connect.php");
if($_GET['id'] and $_GET['data'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $_GET['data'];
$key = $_GET['key'];

    echo $id;
     echo "<br>";
    echo $data;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $key;
    echo "<br>";

if(mysqli_query($connection, "update userbadges set level='$data' where id='$id'"));
    echo 'success';
}
?>
```

Edit Connect.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myusername', 'mypassword', 'leaderboard');
?>
```

Comment: You had better show us the `connect.php` as well

Comment: Remove `;` from `if statement` & use something like `mysqli_error($connection)` and run the script again

Comment: You are not doing any error checking on the `mysqli_` functions. The problem could be anywhere

Comment: @Harshit makes no difference . works localy not on the server

Comment: Use it like 
`if(!mysqli_query($connection, "update userbadges set level='$data' where id='$id'"))
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
else
    echo "Success";`

Comment: Try manually connect to database on current panel  for testing.

Comment: @Harshit that dosent show anything

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: and this `if($_GET['id'] and $_GET['data'])` isn't the best method. Use `if(!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['data']))` or `isset()` - do your variables echo?

Comment: Ralph you are way behind the curve on this one @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's what happens when one drives a '68 Panther and 3 espressos; too fast around the mountainside ;-) *vah-roOOoom!*

Answer (score 0):

You need to be checking everything to do with the `mysqli_` calls

connect.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myusername', 
                                 'mypassword', 'leaderboard');
    if (!$connection) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Your code:

```
<?php
   include("../../config/connect.php");
   if( isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['data'], $_GET['key']) ) {
     $data = $_GET['data'];
     $id   = $_GET['id'];
     $key  = $_GET['key'];

     echo $id;
     echo "<br>";
     echo $data;
     echo "<br>";
     echo $key;
     echo "<br>";

     $result = mysqli_query($connection, 
                            "update userbadges set level='$data' where id='$id'");
     if(! $result) {
         echo mysqli_error($connections);
         exit;
     }
     echo 'database update ' . mysqli_affected_rows($connection) . ' rows';
  } else {

     echo 'One of the required params is missing';
     if ( $_GET ) {
         print_r($_GET);
     }
?>
```

Now if there is a problem like you forgot to change the mysql connection userid and password, or your hosting company use a seperate database server so `localhost` is not right, you will be told about the error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /srv/www/htdocs/Stefan/Pharmacy/backend/module/process3.php on line 22   Also localhost would be correct for the server because even though it wont update the database , it does show data from the dataabse

Comment: `localhost` correct, Ok that was just a shot in the dark to enphasize the need to do all this error checking.

Comment: also the final } shouldnt be there so i removed it and the page now loads . It just shows the echoed id , data and key

Comment: okay, made that change ,but my previous comment still applies . just the echo of id , data and key

Comment: Added a mod to the Ok message to see how many rows MySQL thinks its updating `echo 'database update ' . mysqli_affected_rows($connection) . ' rows;` see what that tells us

Comment: Table 'leaderboard.u' doesn't exist

Comment: Just a `.u`??? have you got some rouge invisible data in one of these script files?

Comment: not that i no of . Like i said , the files and database on the server is a clone of what i have on my local xampp . It works localy

Comment: Is live server unix/linux? I assume XAMPP is on windows

Comment: live server linux , xampp windows . The thing is that it worked on the live server before

Comment: Did that message come after the echo's of $_GET Stuff, i.e. is it from the update or the connection

Comment: Its after the echos of the id data and key

Comment: Delete that whole `mysqli_query` line. Recode it, and FTP it back to the server, see it taht fixes this wierdo.

Comment: I am guessing threre is an odd probably invisible character (or more than one) in that line(s). So cut the line(s) out, and manually rewrite the line. Hopefully that will loose the odd byte of data thats causing us a problem

Comment: Are you sure that the table `userbadges` exists on the LIVE server and ALSO that the **case** of `userbadges` on the live server is all **lower** like your update statement. Remember Windows in **case insensitive** but unix is **case sensitive**!

Comment: im 100% positive that the table exists and is all in lowercase

Comment: Then I am stumped. At least you now know what the problem is now that you have added some error processing to your code. Without being able to get my hand dirty on the real environment I dont know what else I can do for you. Although **have you actually checked** It would not be the first time I was 100% sure of something only to find I was wrong!